# MariaDB not starting in windows 10 after crash

Tags: mariadb, innodb, storage-engine, windows-10, my.ini

MariaDB 10.7 service suddenly stopped in Windows 10 after a crash and the service is not starting. The pop up shows 'windows cannot start mariadb service). The windows event viewer gives the following data:

- InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
- InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=366] log sequence number 424180275 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 408454168.
- InnoDB: unsupported undo header type 16
- InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
- Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
- Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
- Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
- InnoDB: Missing FILE_CREATE, FILE_DELETE or FILE_MODIFY before FILE_CHECKPOINT for tablespace 251

Cannot restart the MaraDB service.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

Locate the configuration file

- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (shortcut for 'run'), type services.msc, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Find the entry named '**MariaDB**', right click on it, select properties
- You should see something like `"F:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.7\bin\mysqld.exe" "--defaults-file=F:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.7\data\my.ini" "MariaDB"`

`F:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB 10.7\data\my.ini` is the location for the configuration file **my.ini**.

For Linux users find the configuration file location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location

**Step 2:**

- Open the configuration file (**my.ini** in Windows, **my.cnf** in Linux) in any available editor (ex. Notepad in Windows)
- add `innodb_force_recovery=1` after `[mysqld]`
- Save the file

Now try starting the server (You can start it from the Windows service manager we used to find the configuration file. In Linux, the command `service mariadb start` would be suffice).

*Note:*

`innodb_force_recovery` value can range from 1 to 6. Try higher values if smaller ones fail. If it works for 5 and above, it is likely that the data is corrupt. On table operations it will produce errors like:

- table is readonly,
- mysql error 194 Tablespace is missing for a table

In this case:

1. Locate the data directory in the configuration file (ex. `datadir=C:/ProgramData/MariaDB/MariaDB 10.7/data`)
2. create a new data directory (ex. `C:/ProgramData/MariaDB/MariaDB 10.7/data2`)
3. Update the value of `datadir=<C:/ProgramData/MariaDB/MariaDB 10.7/data2>` in the configuration file and save.
4. Start the server.

**STEP 3:**

If the server starts peacefully, dont forget to remove the `innodb_force_recovery=X` line from my.ini and restart.

I hope this helps someone struggling to start MariaDB in Windows after a corrupted InnoDB engine failing to start.